# List files whose changes (diff) contain a given string?

Tags: git, git-diff

Is there a simple git command to list files whose diffs contain a given string, or will I have to iterate?

I need to commit a refactoring (method name change) separately from other changes, so I need to identify files whose diffs contain the new method name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `-S` (string) or `-G` (regexp) parameters of the `diff` command to filter with a specific string.

```
git diff --name-only -S"your_method_name"
```

And only files where this specific string appears in the changes will show up in the list.

Take a look here in [the doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff--Sltstringgt) :

> `-S<string>`
>
> Look for differences that change the number of occurrences of the specified string (i.e. addition/deletion) in a file. Intended for the scripter’s use.
>
> It is useful when you’re looking for an exact block of code (like a struct), and want to know the history of that block since it first came into being: use the feature iteratively to feed the interesting block in the preimage back into -S, and keep going until you get the very first version of the block.

Comment: The difference between `-S` and `-G` is not limited to string vs. regex. See [this example](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt--Gltregexgt) on the difference between these two options.